# On the weekend vs this weekend

Tags: american-english, adverbs, time

Could you tell me which sounds natural?

1. I will finish it on the weekend.
2. I will finish it this weekend.

How does "this weekend" differ from "on the weekend?"

I heard that the time expressions which differ based on when it's spoken like tomorrow or today don't require preposition and that those which don't change like January or Sunday require "on," "in" and so on.

If it is true, is it possible to say "I'm going to Canada this January.

Comment: Worth looking at: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/93994/228732

Comment: As has been pointed out several times on this site, Her Majesty and her subjects never do things "ON" the weekend. They do things "on" Saturday, and "on" Sunday, but NEVER "on" the weekend. They do things AT the weekend and OVER the weekend (seldom "during" the weekend).

Comment: Excuse me. But some web sites say "on the weekend" is correct.

Comment: @祐一浅野 We do not usually say "on the weekend" in Britain.

Comment: Sorry. Right, I found that. I should have added I wanted to know about American English.

Comment: I speak American English and never say *on the weekend*. It's *over the weekend*. *This weekend*, as in the OP's second sentence is also fine.

Answer (score -1):

I think the more natural one it's definitely "I will finish it this weekend."

Comment: You think?  Could you please explain why.  That would make a much better answer.